# Regex lazy quantifier vs negation class in MarkDown source

Tags: regex, perl, performance, markdown

I'm looking through the [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) code written in Perl by John Gruber, and there is a sub called `_Detab` that converts tabs to spaces while preserving the indentation of the text. The line of code in question is 1314 in Markdown.pl:

```
$text =~ s{(.*?)\t}{$1.(' ' x ($g_tab_width - length($1) % $g_tab_width))}ge;
```

Wouldn't this cause unnecessary backtracking? Wouldn't the following pattern perform more efficiently?

```
/([^\t\n]*)\t/
```

Or am I missing something? Thanks.

BTW, I'm only negating `\n` and not `\r` because all line breaks are standardized to `\n` beforehand.

Comment: This is the first time I ever understood a line of perl! no `$_` or `@_` or anything!

Comment: @Kobi. Haha, when I first started getting into programming, my learning path was HTML -> JavaScript -> Perl. But I haven't touched Perl in ten years.

Comment: @Kobi: If you see the `$_` (whose name, by the way, is “*it*”), then you are probably looking at not very good Perl code. *It* works best when *it’s* seen least, in little blocks where *its* default nature shines through, like `for (@list} { s/foo/bar/g }`.

Comment: If you're just looking at one-line blocks, those look better as statements: `s/foo/bar/g for @list;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't guess when you can benchmark:

```
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

my $source = "\t\thello\n\t\t\tworld\n" x 100;
my $g_tab_width = 8;

my ($textU, $textN);

cmpthese(-3, {
  ungreedy => sub {
    $textU = $source;
    $textU =~ s{(.*?)\t}{$1.(' ' x ($g_tab_width - length($1) % $g_tab_width))}ge;
  },

 negated => sub {
    $textN = $source;
    $textN =~ s{([^\n\t]*)\t}{$1.(' ' x ($g_tab_width - length($1) % $g_tab_width))}ge;
  },
});

die "whoops" unless $textN eq $textU; # ensure they do the same thing
```

I find that the non-greedy version (as it appears in the Markdown source) is roughly 40% faster than the negated character class you suggest:

```
           Rate  negated ungreedy
negated  1204/s       --     -30%
ungreedy 1718/s      43%       --
```

My guess would be that matching `.` is more efficient than the negated character class, which makes up for the extra backtracking.  More tests would be necessary to confirm that.

Comment: Have you done the warm-up execution of the exchange test sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  This would cause unnecessary backtracking. Yes, your pattern would be more efficient.

Most people don't really understand or think about how regexps work and/or just do things the way they've been taught.  I don't know the particulars of this code or the author, but that's a very common regexp you'll see in perl code.

And, to be honest, for most use cases it doesn't really make that much of a difference.

Comment: It may cause more backtracking, but it's still more efficient than the alternative.  See the benchmark results in my answer.